# Spring AOP:Cannot resolve method to a unique method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

Below is the aspect java code:

```
public class ParamAspect {
    public void beforeMethodExecution(String name){
         System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    }
    public void beforeMethodExecution(Employee employee){
         System.out.println("Employee Name: " + employee.getName());
    }
}
```

Below is the context.xml file:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="empName" expression="execution(void com.model.Employee.setName(String)) and args(name1)"/>
    <aop:pointcut id="empl" expression="execution(void com.model.Employee.setEmployee(com.model.Employee)) and args(empl)"/>
    <aop:aspect ref="aspect">
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="empName" method="beforeMethodExecution" arg-names="name1"/>
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="empl" method="beforeMethodExecution" arg-names="empl"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

The error I got while executing this is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve method 'beforeMethodExecution' to a unique method. Attempted to resolve to overloaded method with the least number of parameters, but there were 2 candidates.
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.findMethodWithMinimalParameters(BeanUtils.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.findMethodWithMinimalParameters(BeanUtils.java:231)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.resolveSignature(BeanUtils.java:332)
at org.springframework.aop.config.MethodLocatingFactoryBean.setBeanFactory(MethodLocatingFactoryBean.java:72)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
... 38 more
```

But again, if I change the method name of the aspect from

```
`public void beforeMethodExecution(Employee employee){`
```

To

```
`public void beforeMethodExec(Employee employee){`
```

and change the same in context.xml from

```
<aop:before pointcut-ref="empl" method="beforeMethodExecution" arg-names="empl"/>
```

To

```
<aop:before pointcut-ref="empl" method="beforeMethodExec" arg-names="empl"/>
```

Then the code works fine.

Please let me know why the same name method throwing exception.

Comment: Take a look at this http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/spring-framework-2.5.3/test/org/springframework/aop/aspectj/overloaded-advice-tests.xml.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="empName" expression="execution(void com.model.Employee.setName(String)) and args(name1)"/>
    <aop:pointcut id="empl" expression="execution(void com.model.Employee.setEmployee(com.model.Employee)) and args(empl)"/>
    <aop:aspect ref="aspect">
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="empName" method="beforeMethodExecution(String)"/>
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="empl" method="beforeMethodExecution(com.model.Employee)"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. your example works if I use this: `<aop:before pointcut-ref="empName" method="beforeMethodExecution(java.lang.String)"/>`.